# Are not they are same? Problem with calling vector element

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

```
vector< vector<int> > vec_c(3);

//Code #1
for(int i = 0; i < vec_c.size(); i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < vec_c[i].size(); j++){
      cout << vec_c[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}

//Code #2
cout << "It is here" << vec_c[0][0] << endl;
```

So the first part of my code runs smoothly and outputs the vector without any problem, however when I am trying to call an element in the vector seperatly it shows "Segmentation fault". I am not sure why, because basically both of them are doing the same thing.

Comment: 2nc code isn't checking if the access is valid, if any of the vectors is empty, you have an access out of bounds, leading to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Yeah I am understanding that, but when the code #1 runs it first should run throught cout << vec_c[i][j] << " "; which is basicly the same as code #2. Cause i starts with 0 and j starts with 0.

Comment: We need to top guessing. In order to do that you need to provide a code example that reproduces the behavour you are experiencing. Use [mcve] as inspiration. The true beauty of the MRE is it'shard to make one without reducing the noise level around the bug to the point where you stare a few seconds, mumble a few curses, and then fix the bug without any help at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vec_c[0]` returns an empty `std::vector<int>`. Hence, `vec[0][0]` is invalid.

The reason that your first example doesn't fail is that:

```
for(int j = 0; j < vec_c[i].size(); j++){
```

checks for the size of `vec_c[0]`, which is 0, so the loop has no actual iterations.